# Cannot resolve method 'setOnItemClickListener(anonymous com.app.app.adapters.ServerApater.OnItemClickListener)?

Tags: java, android

So I'm trying to create an intent which would play current streaming video in an external player but I'm stuck with this setOnItemClickListener being red and can't fix it.

Here's my code:

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static ImageView imgBack;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        imgBack=findViewById(R.id.img_back);

        imgBack.setOnItemClickListener(new ServerApater.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, CommonModels obj, int position, ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder holder) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(obj.getStremURL()), "video/*");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"));
            }
        });


    }
```

And please don't call it duplicate of a few similar questions since I looked up everywhere and can't get the answer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a wrong listener, you need ***OnClickListener*** instead of *OnItemClickListener*, it should be like this:

```
imgBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(obj.getStremURL()), "video/*");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"));
            }
        });
```